# What is the root meaning of the name 'Samovojska'?

Tags: этимология, значения

I have seem alternative spellings of this name listed as

- Samovojska
- Samovojsky
- Samovosky
- Samosky

Is this a Rus surname?

What is the origin or root meaning of this surname?

Comment: These last names don't sound like typical Russian last names. It's likely, however, that they have Slavic roots. According to Bing Translator, the word “само/samo” means “only” and “войска/vojska”  means “army” in Bulgarian.

Comment: @Yury could there be a relation to the word [Шамов|Shamov](http://www.genway.ru/lib/allfam/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/?keyfam=%D0%A8%D0%B0&page=7)?

Comment: I don't think that they are related.

Comment: This is not a Russian surname at all, Russian feminine surnames end with -aya, not with -a.

Comment: @Anixx thanks for the downvote. How would I have known except ask here?

Comment: @New Alexandria no downvote from me here.

Answer (score 1):

Samovojska is croatian surname.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://russian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://russian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Part of question is "Is this a Rus surname?". So "Samovojska is croatian surname." is part of answer. One atom of information, which can be useful for author of question. Yes, it`s not comprehensive, but still useful.

Answer (score 0):

The last one is from Poland (or Ukraine or other surround territories). The root actually refers to the native territory of this person - city or village.

usefull reference about russian last names http://www.genway.ru/lib/allfam/

Comment: Hello Oleg and welcome to the site. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @OlegButuzov I would appreciate that, too.  My Russian lang. learning is very early, and your links would help me learn quicker via questions that are important to my life!  Thanks :)

Comment: I found a reference to a name in the spelling of *[Самовский](http://www.genway.ru/lib/allfam/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/?keyfam=%D0%A1&page=10)*

Comment: For what it's worth, "Samoski" does not sound like a Polish name to me and a Google search doesn't seem to yield and believable Polish results.

Comment: Looks like this site is gathering statistics on last name usage and pretends that it resembles etymology of the surname. For instance [Самофалов](http://www.genway.ru/lib/allfam/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) is claimed to be "50% of Russian origin, 5% - Ukrainian, 10% - Belorussian, 30% from languages of other Russian nations (tatarian, mordovian, buriat, etc.), 5% from Bulgarian or Serbian languages. This is nonsence in terms of etymology. And "the root actually refers to the native territory of this person - city or village" is standard ending of every article.